# query time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have users table and polls table. Assume the tables are quite big, which query would be more efficient in Rails:

```
User.find(user_id).polls.where('category = ?',category)
Poll.where('user_id = ? AND category = ?',user_id,category)
```

You may assume a user can't have too many polls(maybe in average 100 polls). And user_id and category are both indexed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is equivalent to this:

```
user  = User.find(user_id)
polls = user.polls.where(:category => category)
```

The `User.find` will issue a

```
select * from users where id = ?
```

and then the `user.polls.where(...)` part will do a:

```
select * from polls where user_id = ? and category = ?
```

Oddly enough, that's exactly what the plain `Poll.where(...)` will do.

So the second should be quicker since it doesn't do the `select ... from users`. OTOH, if you already have the user then `user.polls.where(...)` would probably make more sense.